# How can white fight for the initiative in the open Tarrasch french

Tags: opening, french-defense, 1.e4

In the French tarrasch after black plays c5, how can white fight for the initiative. I played the closed tarrasch and really enjoy the positions reached after Korchnoi's gambit and want to reach a conceptually similar position, ie, white sacrifices a pawn or takes some long term weaknesses for activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an answer to this. With 3..c5, Black has said, "I refuse to be tied down, Weaken my Pawns if you like, but I will have my freedom!" You allowed him to say that when you played 3.Nd2.